# Axios POST to server returns empty string

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, reactjs

I have a ReactJS form, in which you can enter a new username, which is sent to the server via axios POST and finally saved to a database.
When I click "add" (and thus submit the form), however, it does not save the username I typed into the form input, but returns an empty string.

This is the code for the form including the submit-function:

```
addUser (e) {

    var data = {
        entry: this.state.currentname
    };

    axios.post('users/newuser', 
        data, {
        headers: {"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"} 
        })
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <form onSubmit={this.addUser} encType="multipart/form-data">
                <label>New username:</label>
                <input name="username" value={this.state.currentname} onChange={this.handleChange}></input>
                <button type="submit" >Add</button>
            </form>

            <h1>Current Users: </h1>
            <ul>
                {this.state.users.map((name, n) =>
                    <li key={"user_"+n}>{name.username}</li>
                )}
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
}
```

`users` is the file which contains my curd functions. Here is how I'm currently adding data to the database:

```
router.route('/newuser')
.post(function (req,res) {
    var newUser = new Todo();
    newUser.username = req.body.entry;
    newUser.save(function (err) {
        if(err) 
            res.send(err);
        res.send('User added successfully!');
    });
})
```

Unfortunately, I'm not exactly sure what is going wrong, but I assume that I'm not requesting the username correctly in `users.js`, since it does insert new data into my database, without a username though.

This is my folder structure (don't know if it's relevant):

```
-client
  public
    -index.html
  src
    -App.js(contains the form)
-server.js
-routes
  -users.js
```

What am I doing wrong exactly and how can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

So I'm not sure if this is the best way to solve it or if there are better ways (I won't mark my own answer as correct answer since I don't know how correct it is).

What I did was the following:
I added a query parameter to the string in my `axios.post` request and called for that parameter value in node.js in the function where I insert new data.

These are the parts, which I changed:

App.js:

```
axios.post('users/newuser?username='+data.entry, 
    data, {
    headers: {"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"} 
    })
    .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

user.js:

```
router.route('/newuser')
    .post(function (req,res) {
    var newUser = new Todo();
    newUser.username = req.body.username;
    newUser.save(function (err) {
        if(err) 
            res.send(err);
            res.send('User added successfully!');
        });
    })
```